# Unable to retrieve value from and ID column (Numeric) from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to extract value from a MySQL table to a dropdown control in my php page.

Everything works fine except I am not able to retrieve the data from first column which is set as primary key and auto increment. The column is named as `ID`.

Based on my findings, I could use the adjacent column `Dept` and I can retrieve the value without any issues but this doesn't serve my purpose as the output of `Dept` contains long words (Eg: Department names)

Current Statement

```
echo "<option value='$row[Dept]'>$row[Dept]</option>";
```

Output of above statement when looking at the source code is as below

```
<option value=''>Select One</option><option value='Administration'>Administration</option><option value='Finance'>Finance</option><option value='Human Resource'>Human Resource</option><option value='Information Technology'>Information Technology</option>
```

When I try

```
echo "<option value='$row[ID]'>$row[Dept]</option>";
```

The output is

```
<option value=''>Select One</option><option value=''>Administration</option><option value=''>Finance</option><option value=''>Human Resource</option><option value=''>Information Technology</option>
```

I cross checked the DB and the ID column has numbers in MySQL Table. Please advise.

Comment: please share your sql query

Comment: 1)are you using select * from table? 2) does column ID exist?

Comment: 1. complex variable notations are _not_ resolved correctly in double quoted strings, that is documented. You need to use string concatenation or curly brace notation for this. 2. `$row[Dept]` contains a reference to the assumed _constant_ `Dept` as index which is most likely not what you wanted to express. This should throw a warning, most likely you meant `$row['Dept']` instead.

Comment: It would be preferable to use `echo "<option value='{$row['ID']}'>{$row['Dept']}</option>";`. Be aware that the indexes are case sensitive, so it will not work if the field is named 'id' or 'Id'.

Comment: Is column ID included on your query?

Comment: Sorry, friends. I was so dump that I missed to query and ID column and started complaining on the rest of the code. I feel embarrassed now. Thanks to all for your valuable time.

Comment: I was only using  `$sql = "SELECT Dept FROM comdept";` instead of  `$sql = "SELECT ID, Dept FROM comdept";`